# Product of Sigma Locally Finite Bases

Tags: general-topology

The Nagata-Smirnov theorem tells us that for a $T_3$ space $X$, $X$ is metrizable if and only if X has a sigma-locally finite basis. I also know that if $X_i$ is a countable collection of metrizable spaces, then the product of $X_i$ under the product topology is metrizable too. Hence, if a collection of topologies have a sigma-locally finite basis, then so does their product. I'm having trouble seeing directly why this is true, without invoking the metrization theorem.

I don't need a rigorous proof, I'm just having trouble visualizing how this could be possible. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you see how the product of two (or generally finitely many) $\sigma$-locally finite bases is $\sigma$-locally finite in the product of two (or finitely many) spaces?

Comment: Yes. The finite construction is very obvious to me. It's that when I go to an infinite setting, I have potentially infinite coordinate spaces to worry about, so I'm not sure how to force local finiteness.

Comment: But all but finitely many factors in a basic open set must be the whole space. So you look at $\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \mathscr{S}_n$ as a basis, where $$\mathscr{S}_n = \mathscr{B}_1 \times \dotsc \times \mathscr{B}_n \times \{X_{n+1}\} \times \{X_{n+2}\} \times \dotsc.$$

Comment: Of course. This didn't occur to me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be countable . For $a\in A$ and $n\in \mathbb N$ let $B_{a,n}$ be a locally finite family in the space $X_a$ such that $\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}B_{a,n}$ is a base for $X_a .$

For finite $S\subset A,$ and for $T=\{n(a) :a\in S\}\subset \mathbb N$ let $U\in V(S,T)$ iff  $U=\prod_{a\in A}V_a$ where  $V_a=X_a$ if $a\not \in S$ and $V_a\in B_{a,n(a)}$ if $a\in S.$

Now show that the union  of all $V(S,T)$ is a base for $\prod_{a\in A}X_a$ and that each $V(S,T)$ is locally finite.